# opaque type with create-react-app + Flow

Tags: reactjs, flowtype, create-react-app

First of all I want to say, a short THANK YOU for contributing to this amazing platform, which helped me out plenty times. with that said:

I am facing a challenge with create-react-app and flow, using opaque type alias: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/opaque-types/

Here is my setup:

1. create-react-app@1.4.3
2. flow-bin@0.61.0

[Find screenshot of the version of my flow-bin here (used 'flow version')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcNKt.png)

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "reactProjectWithFlow",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "grid-styled": "^2.0.0-11",
    "material-ui": "^0.19.4",
    "mobx": "^3.4.1",
    "mobx-react": "^4.3.5",
    "react": "^16.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.1.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.17"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-flow": "^6.23.0",
    "flow-bin": "^0.61.0"
  }
}
```

My Editor is Atom with the Nuclide packages:
https://nuclide.io/

I found this little sweet note:
https://flow.org/en/docs/tools/create-react-app/

I followed this approach to make it work as stated in the previous post:
https://flow.org/en/docs/install/

When I run "yarn start" it is fine and works.
Flow is also up and running in the editor.

I would like to simulate private and public fields in my classes and figured out that this may be accomplished with opaque type alias with flow, as stated above.

When I just try to do a single test how this works (I am new to flow) e.g.

`opaque type ID = string;`

If I put this in a source file, then flow works just fine, or better said, I do not get any flow errors, but my development server complains:

[Find a screenshot here with the compilation error using opaque keyword](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pub4N.png)

When I omit the opaque keyword if works fine.

[Find screenshot with working compilation when opaque is omitted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVeJX.png)

I am thankful for support,

Best regards

Comment: what's the version of `flow` used in your project ?

Comment: 0.61.0 - I also edited the post and attached a screenshot of the results of 'flow version'